# How to set array values in a Windows batch file loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to set values in a Windows batch file, it's not working, and I have no idea why.  Here's my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set idx=-1
set STRING_LIST=

for %%v in (string1 string2 string3) do (
    set /A idx+=1
    echo [!idx!] %%v

    set STRING_LIST[!idx!]=%%v
)

:: Why is my list empty here??
echo STRING_LIST= %STRING_LIST%
pause
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just answered my own question.  First, I shouldn't have been setting the `STRING_LIST` array at the beginning of my script.  Second, I needed to fix how I was trying to display the list item values.

Here's the final script I ended up with

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion enableextensions

set idx=-1

echo Populate the list:
for %%v in (string1 string2 string3) do (
    set /A idx+=1
    echo [!idx!] %%v

    set STRING_LIST[!idx!]=%%v
)
echo.

echo Individual list item values:
echo %STRING_LIST[0]%
echo %STRING_LIST[1]%
echo %STRING_LIST[2]%
echo.

echo All list item values:
for /L %%f in (0,1,!idx!) do (echo !STRING_LIST[%%f]!)
echo.

pause
```

Comment: Just a note to mention that as your final value of the variable named `idx` was set within another code block, you don't need to delay it's expansion outside of that block. Instead of `(0,1,!idx!)` you could have used `(0,1,%idx%)`.

Comment: Great, thank you for pointing that out.  I was definitely coding fast and loose in trying to get things to work. =P

Answer (score 1):

I know you've solved your issue, *(you were trying to show the values of a previously undefined variable instead of the ones you were after)*. This is simply to expand upon the advice in my now deleted comment regarding undefining any existing `STRING_LIST[…` variables and showing all those newly defined at the end, as that is what I think you were trying to do.

```bat
@For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set STRING_LIST[ 2^>NUL')Do @Set "%%A="
@Set "idx=-1"
@For %%A In (string1 string2 string3)Do @(Set /A idx+=1
    Call Echo [%%idx%%] %%A&Call Set "STRING_LIST[%%idx%%]=%%A")
@Set STRING_LIST[ 2>NUL&&Pause||Exit /B
```